# "fetch --all" in a git bare repository doesn't synchronize local branches to the remote ones

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-bare

I'm trying to synchronize periodically a git bare repository, my local branches are created using the "--track" option. here is my config (without unnecessary things):

```
[core]
        bare = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:Ummon/D-LAN.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "website"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/website
```

I must use the 'cp' command to update the local branches:

```
 git fetch --all
 cp -r refs/remotes/origin/* refs/heads
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of copying the ref files around (bad bad!) use `git update-ref`

Note that you can have what you wanted pretty easily to a bare repository when pushing instead of pulling.

Use this:

```
 git clone --mirror . /tmp/bareclone
```

to create the bare repository that you want to keep completely in synch
Now, to synch all the branches to the bareclone mirror, use

```
 git push /tmp/bareclone --mirror
```

NOTE that this will also remove any heads that aren't in the source repo but (still) are in the bareclone. Also note that you can use send-pack instead of push there because this interface is rather lowlevel and actually implemented by send-pack

HTH

---

As the commenter noted, I slighly avoided the subject that it doesn't seem possible at once to do the inverse. However, you can get a long ways towards the goal by doing something slightly advanced like:

#### 1. Simple, safe and pretty unexciting.

```
git fetch $url -- $(git ls-remote -h $url |
    while read sha ref; do echo "$ref:refs/remotes/fetched/${ref#refs/heads/}"; done)
```

Set `url=git://your.server/project.git' e.g.

I made sure that the refs are created in a moderately safe location. The effect very similar to doing.

```
git remote add fetched $url --fetch
```

So there is nothing much, *but* it shows you how to use plumbing commands to achieve it, so we can now adapt them to our needs:

#### 2. Fetch directly into local branches (heads)

Now **if you are sure you know what you're doing** you can use the following style to get the branches duplicated locally:

```
git init --bare .
git fetch $url -- $(git ls-remote -h $url |
    while read sha ref; do echo "$ref:$ref"; done)
```

> <sub>**Note**: if you want to *force* update (e.g. when there is no fast-forward pull because of an upstream rebase, reset, filter-branch, or amended commit (in general -- any rewritten history) replace `echo "$ref:$ref"` by `echo "+$ref:$ref"`</sub>; (Thanks [Dov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449215/dov-grobgeld))

#### 3. The full monty

This could also be combined, so you can have a remote definition too. *I'd recommend that because it will mean that the local branches are actually tracking the ones from the remotes, and you'll have better insulation/recovery options if you accidentally clobber some of the local commits on these branches with these powerful fetch commands*

```
git init --bare .
git remote add fetched $url --fetch
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' -- 'refs/remotes/fetched/' |
    while read ref; do git branch -t "$(basename "$ref")" "$ref"; done
```

Have fun, HTH

Comment: Thx, I do that for each branch: `git update-ref refs/heads/master refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing as the `git push --mirror` but initiating from the receiving repository. If the source repository is hosted elsewhere such as github, you can't use git push.

Comment: @Mark: I had evaded that issue in the original answer. I have updated the answer with hints and tricks that you may like :)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just doing `git fetch` then doing `git update-ref` to move from refs/remotes/remotename/$ref to refs/heads/$ref. Not exactly the safest thing to do, but in my case it's a read only mirror and did the job. Your solutions look much better though, and I may end up changing it to the second method you used.

Comment: Yeah - actually, you'd need to take your `update-ref` approach any subsequent update when doing the 3rd approach (the full monty), so it is valuable info, I sort of forgot about updating things :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I was looking for a way of updating a clone. Just one comment about your example 2. above, I added a + to the reference so that it reads `do echo "+$ref:$ref"`.

Comment: Shouldn't a `git clone --mirror` with `git fetch --all` be sufficient to create a bare r/o repo which tracks all remote branches?

Comment: Just wanted to note that the last solution should be `git for-each-ref`. (I tried to edit it myself but "Edits must be at least 6 characters" and I was only adding 4 :p). This worked great for me. Thanks very much

Comment: Rather than using `basename`, I'd go for parameter expansion and use `git branch -t ${ref#fetched/} $ref` so that you can still have branches names `foo/bar` both on `fetch` and locally.