# What's the git command to pull in all changes from a remote repo?

Tags: git

I have a repo that's forked from a remote repository. I made some changes, the remote repository updated and now I want to pull in all changes from the remote repository, and not care about anything in my local repository. Previously I've been deleting my local repository, then doing a simple fork and clone. There's got to be a better way to do this. What's the magic command?

Comment: Most of the answers here suggest pulling, which means merging. If you're willing to delete your repository, I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

Comment: That's correct, I don't care about the merging. reset --hard was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to throw away commits on your local branch (if you've made any). If that's the case, then you want:

```
# fetch updated branch(es) from origin
git fetch origin

# reset, including your work tree, to origin's master branch
# make sure you have your master branch checked out first!
# and also that you don't mind throwing away local commits or
# uncommitted modifications
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Some assumptions: `master` is the old branch, where you commit some changes. Now `other` is the fresh checkout from the remote `origin`.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b other origin/master
```

With

```
git diff other..master
```

you can compare the two branches. And at last with

```
git checkout other
git merge master
```

you merge them. Another useful tool here is [cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html), with that you can merge only some interesting commits into a branch

```
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

Comment: Could add the commands to diff and then merge the two branches?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my answer here helps

["fetch --all" in a git bare repository doesn't synchronize local branches to the remote ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559321/fetch-all-in-a-git-bare-repository-doesnt-synchronize-local-branches-to-the/5559586#5559586)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to branch, like this:

```
git commit -m "All my latest stuff I don't care about"
git branch newstuff refs/remotes/origin/master 
git pull
```

And now you've got all of your new stuff. Of course this is assuming you want to keep the old stuff.

Answer (score 0):

(Considering your branch is `master` and the remote is named `origin`)

First update your `origin` with:

`git fetch origin`

Now, if you have not committed since your last update you can simply do this:

`git rebase master origin/master`

If you have some commits done, this **fast-forward** rebase won't work. In that case you can do:

`git branch -d master (to remove your local master branch)`

`git checkout -b master origin/master`

---

Diffing before merging:

If you want to see what changed before doing the `merge` do:

`git fetch origin (always to bring the changes from the remote)`

`git diff master origin/master`

Comment: Git won't be too eager to delete a checked-out branch. Your rebase also doesn't do what you think - it's using master as the base. I think you meant `git rebase origin/master master`. But of course, I wouldn't use rebase, just `git merge --ff-only origin/master`.