# Git not fetching newest commits?

Tags: git, msysgit

When I type git show-ref from a repo I get HASH-B (placeholder for an actual hash) for the refs/heads/master but HASH-A for the refs/remotes/origin/master. These are both bare repos. When I do a fetch or fetch --all, it says "Fetching origin", but nothing else.

What could be going on? Why might this fetch not be occurring?

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments in Ryan's answer it looks like you need to merge your master with origin/master.  You can do a `git pull`, instead of `git fetch`, or from *your* master, do a `git merge origin/master`

`git pull` does a fetch and than merge, whereas `git fetch` just fetches the remote branches, but doesn't merge them.

Comment: But you can't do a merge or pull in a bare repo. Do I need to create a clone of the bare downstream, merge with the upstream, then push to the downstream, followed by the upstream?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559321/fetch-all-in-a-git-bare-repository-doesnt-synchronize-local-branches-to-the) is another question that I think describes your situation.  If it doesn't I'll agree with Ryan that you need to update/clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be going on?

You don't seem to have given any conflicting information. `master` and `origin/master` can and regularly do point at different commits, and once you've fetched from a remote, successive fetches give no output. What's the problem?

Comment: So I checked in a change to the parent repo and am trying to get it to the child repo, but the change is not propagating. How do I get the change to the child repo? [ and by parent I believe I am referring to upstream ]

Comment: You'll have to show some information. Update your question with, for instance, the output of `git log --oneline master` on both repos and of `git remote -v` on the repo you're trying to fetch into (not from) and other relevant information you can think of.